# Firebase functions - Multiple functions & dependency management

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

#### Background

I want to better understand how the firebase CLI handles the deployment of multiple firebase functions, from different files, and how it handles dependencies only used in certain files.

#### Scenario

Suppose I have mutiple firebase functions. According to the documentation, the recommended way to split my functions would be like below:

```js
// - - - - - - - - - -
// first-function.ts

import { onCall } from 'firebase-functions/v2/http'
import FirstFunctionDependency from 'foo'

export const firstFunction = onCall(async (req) => {
  // this function uses 'FirstFunctionDependency'
  const result = await FirstFunctionDependency.doSomething(req.data)
  return result
})

// - - - - - - - - - -
// second-function.ts

import { onCall } from 'firebase-functions/v2/http'
import SecondFunctionDependency from 'bar'

export const secondFunction = onCall(async (req) => {
  // this function uses 'SecondFunctionDependency'
  const result = await SecondFunctionDependency.doSomethingElse(req.data)
  return result
})

// - - - - - - - - - -
// index.ts

export * from './first-function.ts'
export * from './second-functiont.ts'
```

Let's then say `firstFunction` gets called, and experiences a cold start. During the spin-up and initialisation of the instance, **will it import and parse `SecondFunctionDependency` from the `bar` module?**

#### Lazy Loading

The Firebase documentation talks about lazy loading dependencies, and something I am thinking of doing, but given the scenario above, it is unclear to me if lazy loading is required, or if the firebase CLI will package each function separately, and only deploy it on its own, along with its separate dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let's then say firstFunction gets called, and experiences a cold start. During the spin-up and initialisation of the instance, will it import and parse SecondFunctionDependency from the bar module?

Yes.  This has nothing to do with Cloud Functions.  It's just how TypeScript/JavaScript works.  All top-level imports are evaluated eagerly - they are not lazy at all.  Importing a file necessarily imports and executes all other top-level imports defined in that file.

> it is unclear to me if lazy loading is required, or if the firebase CLI will package each function separately, and only deploy it on its own, along with its separate dependencies?

The Firebase CLI does not do anything special to the source code upon deployment.  Each function gets a full copy of all the source code of all functions in the deployment. Each function will run your index file, and that will import *everything* it encounters and run all code at the top level.

It's not necessary to lazy load anything unless you see there is some excessive usage that you detect using your own benchmarks, and you personally feel that needs to be improved.  We can't tell you what you need to do - only you can know from your own requirements and runtime observations. I can tell you that most people probably don't worry about this at all, but again, you have to decide this for yourself.

Comment: awesome thanks for your response.

i am keen to lazy load because i have a few particular dependencies that are very heavy (2MB gzipped), and only used in a couple of firebase functions. Given I am not using a minimum instance count, my app regularly experiences cold starts.

Given your response, I will lazy load those dependencies within those functions, and will hopefully see some improved cold start time on the functions that don't use it!